# Could not build url for endpoint 'topic' with values ['type']. Did you mean 'topic_func' instead?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to create dynamic urls in jinja and I need to pass the selected value from the html page to the flask to create the new web page.

I have topics in a dropdown menu and when I click the link, the information needs to be passed to the flask that which link was selected and what will be displayed on that page but an error occurred saying could not build endpoint for url. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

The dashboard.py file is here:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
     #topic is a list of topics for the dropdown menu
     return render_template("home.html",topic=topics)
@app.route('/topic', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def topic_func():
    result = request.args.get('type')
    print(result) #should print what was the topic that was clicked in the dropdown menu 
    return render_template(index.html, value=result)
```

This is home.html and also I am unable to get the value of type. It is printing {{each}} when it should print the value of the topic selected. How can I solve this?:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">

{% for each in topics %}

      <a href="{{url_for('topic', type='{{each}}')}}">{{each}}</a>

{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather structure your code like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">

    {% for each in topics %}

          <a href="{{url_for('topic_func', type='')}}{{each}}">{{each}}</a>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Remarks two things:

1. In `url_for` I replaced the route `topic` with the the function `topic_func`. This is because `url_for` looks for a function. So you have to pass it *the name of a function*.
2. I moved the value to send `{{each}}`, after the two braces of `url_for`. The reason is that by leaving them inside the quotes, the function `url_for` does not understand it as a jinja variable but it considers that it is the exact value that you want to send. So you're going to have, on the python side:

Python:

```
@app.route('/topic', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def topic_func():
    result = request.args.get('type')
    print(result)  # {{each}}
```